# boot from old internal HDD after fresh Windows install on new SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I replaced the HDD (Win10 Pro Bld # > 1800 can't remember exactly) on a V502UX Asus with 2 SSDs:

1. 500GB 2.5" SATA III Samsung 870EVO on which I installed a fresh Windows 10 Pro (21H2 Bld #19044.1766).
2. 250GB M.2 SATA III Samsung 860EVO on which I installed some apps.

I put the old HDD in a box (caddy?). I didn't do a full backup as most of my important docs were on the cloud and I thought I would still be able to access my other docs on the HDD.
After connecting my old HDD to the USB3 port, the 3 partitions showed up, but my new windows wouldn't allow me to access the Documents folder (and pretty much any other folders) due to ownership issues. I changed the ownership of the Documents folder to my new system and I was able to access them. Then I realized that some of the stuff I needed were stored inside the apps (e.g. some Windows sticky notes, some saved sessions in OneTab, etc.) and I needed to run the apps from the old Windows to access them.
Then I changed the BIOS Boot order and tried to boot from my old drive, but it gets stuck in a restart loop without displaying any errors. I can still boot from my new SSD when I revert back the boot order.

Could the problem be due to the messed up ownership of my Documents folder or Windows profile? If so, how can I fix that?
Could it be that my old HDD is assigned a different drive letter? If so, is it safe to temporarily assign the C letter to my HDD via Diskpart and after I'm done with it swap the drive letters again without causing issues to my new Windows partitions on the SSD (including the hidden 'reserve' partitions?

As a last resort, I also thought of using Dik2VHD and Hyper-V or VirtualBOX to boot my old HDD into a VM, but that seems like a lot of hassle to get just a few bits of leftover data.

What is the safest, quickest, and most convenient way to access that data without ruining my current installation?

Answer (score 0):

The safest thing to do is refrain from tinkering with the old/new installations as you have been doing and proceed to copy everything you can using a Live Linux USB.

Step 1. [Download a live linux ISO](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-download) and create a bootable USB using a program like [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/)

Step 2. Get your computer to boot into Linux using the Live USB you created.

Step 3. When on the linux desktop mount your hard drive and start copying files.

You likely did cause some sort of issue by changing the ownership of your old Windows folder structures. It's not the end of the world though because a little extra research should help you retrieve the files you're after.

For Example:

[Where are OneTab sessions stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535985/how-to-restore-onetab-list-of-tabs-after-computer-crash)

[Where are Sticky Notes stored?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/sticky-note-location/4da6257a-cd82-4644-81a3-703442a3a797)

etc...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a Linux box and live USB. My issue is not so much salvaging the files, as I can already copy them from my current Windows install. What I'm really interested in is booting up my system with the old installation so I can access those apps. I was hoping to achieve that without manually restoring app data, which might be stored in binary or encrypted formats in some cases or otherwise useless unless properly exported.

Comment: have you tried physically uninstalling your SSD and inserting your old hard drive back into it's original position? So rather than going to USB you return the machine to how it was with the old hard drive back into it's original SATA port connection (without the SSD involved).

Comment: I considered that, but would rather find a way that didn't involve opening the laptop twice.

Comment: That's understandable, especially with laptops and all the screws you're left with all over the table. It's not guaranteed to work anyway - clutching at straws to be honest!

Comment: Check this one out:
https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/172574-booting-windows-10-external-hard-disk.html

It does look like there is a difference between USB and SATA with respect to how the boot process works with the drive controller.

Comment: Thanks, it contained some useful points.